# Why Netty uses reference counting instead of just one ByteBuffer per connection when NIO is single-threaded?

Tags: java, real-time, netty, nio, low-latency

I am confused why Netty 5.0 makes you use reference counting for ByteBuffers. Isn't Java NIO supposed to be single-threaded, in other words, one selector thread for many connections? Each client needs its own  `ByteBuffer` and that's it, no pooling should be needed unless I am missing something.

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ByteBuf m = (ByteBuf) msg; // (1)
    try {
        long currentTimeMillis = (m.readUnsignedInt() - 2208988800L) * 1000L;
        System.out.println(new Date(currentTimeMillis));
        ctx.close();
    } finally {
        m.release();
    }
}
```

Source: http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because we don't know exactly what people will do with the ByteBuf. Also we support writing from different threads etc.

Comment: and some connections are idle and thus having a buffer for each channel is wasteful.

Comment: @trustin In my humble opinion, memory is not a problem. **Complexity is a big problem!** Writing from different threads can create all kinds of race conditions for very little to no advantage.

Comment: @PeterMel Memory is a problem when you end up dealing with 100k connections. 100k channels * 4KiB buffer/channel = apx. 400MiB?

Comment: @trustin I would think that 400Mb of ram memory is no problem these days. I run my JVM with several gigabytes of ram memory.